# Should DispatchEvent be the last statement of a function?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Should dispatchEvent must be the last statement of any function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call dispatchEvent, all handlers for that event are immediately called before the rest of the function body where dispatchEvent was called runs. Does that mean that you need to call dispatchEvent as the last thing in a function body? Only if the code that is after the dispatchEvent call somehow depends on something that will be adversely changed when the handlers run.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not， dispatchEvent() can be invoked at anywhere as you wish. What make you to ask this question?

Comment: i had problems previously in my projects... i noticed that they occured mainly when my dispatchEvent was in between the lines of code rathar then being the last statement. Many a times, i noticed even a trace command after the dispatchEvent caused problem ( very high processing, when dispatchEvent is related to mousemovements)

Answer (score 1):

Nope

`dispatchEvent` will fire an event, and the corresponding event handler will be executed immediately after the `dispatchEvent` is invoked.

However, unlike a return, the remaining lines of code *will be executed* **after** the event handler is completely executed

Simple test:

```
//Movie clip (mClip1)

function buzz():void {
    trace("buzz:1");
    dispatchEvent(new Event("justAnotherEvent"));
    trace("buzz:2");
}


//on the stage,

mClip1.addEventListener("justAnotherEvent", ping);

function ping(e:Event):void {
    trace("ping");
}
```

Output:

> buzz:1
>   ping
>   buzz:2

**edit**
I KNOW that using a literal string instead of a `const` for the event type is a bad practice, but as I said, this is just a simple quick down and dirty test.

Comment: Some people might say that using a constant forces you to have a dependency on a Class whose sole puropse is enumeration of constants, which could be seen as bad practice. Once you get to the point where you know enough to evaluate best practices that you were taught in light of new information or conflicting best practices, things become a bit more nuanced than black and white.

Comment: haha well I was beaten up pretty bad earlier on SO for using a string literal in a quick example, so that's just pre-emptive clarification

Comment: Yes, the fact that people can anonymously down vote you can allow things to get pretty nasty.