# Keeping aside loose coupling concept, wht's the difference between function call and dispatchEvent

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

If i keep aside the  loose coupling advantage of Events, what is the difference in the way of working of 
1) Simple function call
2) Dispatching an event

thnx
V.

Comment: Well, i want to hear explanation through Synchronous and Asynchronous methods. I think Functions are used for Synchronous methods while Events is an  Asynchronous approach ? Can anybody throw light on these points. My focus is on "How working of each differs with each other" ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

These are two very different concepts, one performs an action, the other signals "something".

I'm not sure you should put them in the same basket to start with.

Of course it's easy to see the overlaps between them from the standpoint of the results you're trying to achieve but it doesn't follow that they can actually be compared.

Simply put you will end up with a function call , it's just a matter of how you go about it. Call the function directly or dispatch en Event in order to inform that such function should be called...

This question is similar in scope to your previous question , meaning that neither seems to make sense. 
[Should DispatchEvent be the last statement of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270725/should-dispatchevent-be-the-last-statement-of-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

A simple function call is faster (ie there are less steps for the cpu to do). Generally, use dispatchEvent when you need the advantages of loose coupling or when you have multiple components which need to act on some event, and use a function call otherwise.